# "Official" I18N vs. simple resource files

Tags: angular, localization, internationalization

The ["official" way to facilitate I18N in Angular](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html) appears quite complicated to me:

> The i18n template translation process has four phases:
>
> 1. Mark static text messages in your component templates for translation.
> 2. An angular i18n tool extracts the marked messages into an industry standard translation source file.
> 3. A translator edits that file, translating the extracted text messages into the target language, and returns the file to you.
> 4. The Angular compiler imports the completed translation files, replaces the original messages with translated text, and generates a
>      new version of the application in the target language.
>
> You need to build and deploy a separate version of the application for
>   each supported language.

Some quirks are mentioned:

a)

> Translating plural and select messages is a little tricky.
>
> The  tag is empty for plural and select translation units,
>   which makes them hard to correlate with the original template. The
>   XLIFF format doesn't yet support the ICU rules; it soon will.

b)

> Translation file maintenance and id changes
>
> As the application evolves, you will change the i18n markup and re-run
>   the ng-xi18n extraction tool many times. The new markup that you add
>   is not a problem; but most changes to existing markup trigger
>   generation of new ids for the affected translation units.
>
> After an id changes, the translation files are no longer in-sync. All
>   translated versions of the application will fail during
>   re-compilation. The error messages identify the old ids that are no
>   longer valid but they don't tell you what the new ids should be.
>
> Commit all translation message files to source control, especially the
>   English source messages.xlf. The difference between the old and the
>   new messages.xlf file help you find and update id changes across your
>   translation files.

A human translator may need some context info in order to translate a text. So, if you want to provide meaning and description, you can use the following syntax in your templates. The tools will propagate it to the file that is given to the translator.

```
<img [src]="logo" i18n-title="<meaning>|<description>" title="Angular 2 logo" />
```

I would argue that this syntax bloats the markup quite a bit.

So, given all its complexity and quirks, I wonder why you would choose that approach? Why not simply have a JSON file per language that maps (usually stable) keys to texts, load it as a JavaScript object and bind to the keys in your templates? Meanings and descriptions of these keys could be easily provided in an additional file. Accessing texts by keys in language-specific text files is [how it is done in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/propfile.html), by the way.

Comment: This comment shows the differences between angular i18n and ngx-translate. Maybe it helps you to find the advantages and disadvantages. https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/495#issuecomment-291158036